# A problem occurred when checking for the updates

Tags: updates

I recieve an error (red box with white exclamation mark) that states, "A problem occurred when checking for the updates."

When I show the updates, it states that my software is already up to date.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

already (and various other commands) stated within the forum to related issues.

Any advice on how to remove the notification?

When I input `sudo apt-get install -f`
The output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Again, with `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 2 not upgraded.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, post the output here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will fix the problem. Output is not needed. It happens to pipelight, etc.

Comment: @A.B. http://paste.ubuntu.com/13043548/, and now 0 not upgraded for the latter command. However, the error seemingly persists.

Comment: seemingly?  You have no errors. Once again `sudo apt-get install -f` and add the full output into your question.

Comment: @ A.B. I rebooted yet the notification remains, which is odd, I agree, as no errors occur. Not sure what the problem is. Edited the question- 2 not upgraded as the output again.

Comment: Give me the full output of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13045045/ Notification remains.

Comment: Give us the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. I suspect that your system is not finding the latest package indexes. And when you run `sudo apt-get update`, do you see a long list of files being downloaded?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13051081/. Yes I do.

Comment: Run this command and use http://paste.ubuntu.com for the output `LANG=C dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {system("apt-cache policy "$2)}' | awk '/^[a-z].*:$/ {pkg=$0} /Installed/ {var=$2;next} /Candidate/ {var1=$2;next} {if(var!="" && var!=var1) print pkg,var,var1; var=""}'`